# How to remove these unnecessary connections?

Tags: modeling

[image]I'm trying to use simple deform and I separated all sections, but there some ugly connections on wide fragments. Please help me to remove them[image: You can see them on picture](or say what I am doing wrong)
I'm using blender for 2 days and I'm absolute newbie. I will be glad for any help

Comment: Can you add a image of the object in edit mode? It might be due to bad topology

Comment: +1, There is definitely double geometry here that you may not see when the object is straight but that cannot bend with the modifier